# How to resolve Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed with $http.post?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

My angular client has a postrequest that looks like this:

```
$http.post("api/login/",  { foo: 'bar' }).success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.hello = data;
})
```

The server is implemented in express:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');

var request = require('request');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    res.send({message:'hello from api/login'});

});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I click 'login' I get an error:

```
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

How can I resolve this error?
github:https://github.com/dimitri-a/oauth_stuff